# AngularJS window dimensions

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access the window dimensions with AngularJS 1.3 to ultimately calculate the orientation of the screen.

None of the examples I find online works and I am not sure why.

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller("IntroCtrl", function ($scope, $window) {

        var window = angular.element($window);

        console.log('WindowWidth ' + window.innerWidth);
});
```

The console reports:

```
"WindowWidth undefined"
```

What is the correct way to read the values?

Comment: are you minifying the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using $inject instead of angular.element

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller("IntroCtrl", function ($scope, $injector) {

        var window = $injector.get("$window");

        console.log('WindowWidth ' + window.innerWidth);
});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `$injector` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller("IntroCtrl", ['$scope', '$window',function ($scope, $window) {
        console.log('WindowWidth ' + $window.innerWidth);
}]);
```

This will work. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13496/. Working fiddle for the same code

Comment: Sorry but this does not seem to work. Still get innerWidth as undefined.

Comment: Its coming for me in the fiddle. Could you check again and see if you missed something out

Comment: It does work in fiddle, but cannot get it to work in my application. Will try to find out why.

Comment: cool. This provides you with a better solution, so check whats going wrong